# Not able to install postcss-plugin in node app

Tags: node.js, postcss-cli

I'm trying to use css-declaration-sorter but cant get it to install. I have tried installing both postcss-cli and running npx both globally and locally and keep getting error "Plugin Error: Cannot find module 'css-declaration-sorter'.
Here is a snapshot of what I am running:
[image: local dependencies installed and command run.]

I have tried adding path to css-declaration-sorter put to no avail. If I try using postcss  like in example on page I get "postcss command not found." Any input on how to get this to work much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `postcss-cli` locally:

```
$ npm i -D postcss-cli
```

Then run your command again.